# Writing Ubuntu 20.04 driver, problems with compiling it

Tags: c, linux, makefile, compiler-errors, driver

I was writing a code for my driver and i cannot check it because i cannot compile it. I tried to reinstall ubuntu and used all this commands on a clean OS but i faced the same problem so i suppose it's only a problem with library installation.

Code for my driver:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>                 // kmalloc()
#include <linux/uaccess.h>              // copy_to/from_user()
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>

#include <linux/pid.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/device.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Stab linux module for operating system's lab");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");

static int pid = 1;
static int struct_id = 1;

static struct proc_dir_entry *parent;

/*
** Function Prototypes
*/
static int      __init lab_driver_init(void);
static void     __exit lab_driver_exit(void);


/***************** Procfs Functions *******************/
static int      open_proc(struct inode *inode, struct file *file);
static int      release_proc(struct inode *inode, struct file *file);
static ssize_t  read_proc(struct file *filp, char __user *buffer, size_t length,loff_t * offset);
static ssize_t  write_proc(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off);

/*
** procfs operation sturcture
*/
static struct proc_ops proc_fops = {
        .proc_open = open_proc, 
        .proc_read = read_proc,
        .proc_write = write_proc,
        .proc_release = release_proc
};

// net_device
static size_t write_net_device_struct(char __user *ubuf){
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    size_t len = 0;

    static struct net_device *dev;

    read_lock(&dev_base_lock);

    dev = first_net_device(&init_net);
    while(dev){
        len += sprintf(buf+len, "found [%s]\n",     dev->name);
        len += sprintf(buf+len, "base_addr = %ld\n", dev->base_addr);
        len += sprintf(buf+len, "mem_start = %ld\n", dev->mem_start);
        len += sprintf(buf+len, "mem_end = %ld\n\n", dev->mem_end);
        dev = next_net_device(dev);
    }

    read_unlock(&dev_base_lock);

    if (copy_to_user(ubuf, buf, len)){
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    return len;
}

// signal_struct
static size_t write_signal_struct(char __user *ubuf, struct task_struct *task_struct_ref){
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    size_t len = 0;

    struct signal_struct *signalStruct = task_struct_ref->signal;

    len += sprintf(buf,     "live = %d\n",                  atomic_read(&(signalStruct->live)));
    len += sprintf(buf+len, "nr_threads = %d\n",            signalStruct->nr_threads);
    len += sprintf(buf+len, "group_exit_code = %d\n",       signalStruct->group_exit_code);
    len += sprintf(buf+len, "notify_count = %d\n",          signalStruct->notify_count);
    len += sprintf(buf+len, "group_stop_count = %d\n",      signalStruct->group_stop_count);
    len += sprintf(buf+len, "flags = %d\n",                 signalStruct->flags);
    len += sprintf(buf+len, "is_child_subreaper = %d\n",    signalStruct->is_child_subreaper);
    len += sprintf(buf+len, "has_child_subreaper = %d\n",   signalStruct->has_child_subreaper);

    if (copy_to_user(ubuf, buf, len)){
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    return len;
}


/*
** Эта фануция будет вызвана, когда мы ОТКРОЕМ файл procfs
*/
static int open_proc(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc file opend.....\t");
    return 0;
}

/*
** Эта фануция будет вызвана, когда мы ЗАКРОЕМ файл procfs
*/
static int release_proc(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc file released.....\n");
    return 0;
}

/*
** Эта фануция будет вызвана, когда мы ПРОЧИТАЕМ файл procfs
*/
static ssize_t read_proc(struct file *filp, char __user *ubuf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos) {

    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int len = 0;
    struct task_struct *task_struct_ref = get_pid_task(find_get_pid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
    
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc file read.....\n");
    if (*ppos > 0 || count < BUF_SIZE){
        return 0;
    }

    if (task_struct_ref == NULL){
        len += sprintf(buf,"task_struct for pid %d is NULL. Can not get any information\n",pid);

        if (copy_to_user(ubuf, buf, len)){
            return -EFAULT;
        }
        *ppos = len;
        return len;
    }

    switch(struct_id){
        default:
        case 0:
            len = write_net_device_struct(ubuf);
            break;
        case 1:
            len = write_signal_struct(ubuf, task_struct_ref);
            break;
    }

    *ppos = len;
    return len;
}

/*
** Эта фануция будет вызвана, когда мы ЗАПИШЕМ в файл procfs
*/
static ssize_t write_proc(struct file *filp, const char __user *ubuf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos) {

    int num_of_read_digits, c, a, b;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc file wrote.....\n");

    if (*ppos > 0 || count > BUF_SIZE){
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    if( copy_from_user(buf, ubuf, count) ) {
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    num_of_read_digits = sscanf(buf, "%d %d", &a, &b);
    if (num_of_read_digits != 2){
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    struct_id = a;
    pid = b;

    c = strlen(buf);
    *ppos = c;
    return c;
}

/*
** Функция инициализации Модуля
*/
static int __init lab_driver_init(void) {
    /* Создание директории процесса. Она будет создана в файловой системе "/proc" */
    parent = proc_mkdir("lab",NULL);

    if( parent == NULL )
    {
        pr_info("Error creating proc entry");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Создание записи процесса в разделе "/proc/lab/" */
    proc_create("struct_info", 0666, parent, &proc_fops);

    pr_info("Device Driver Insert...Done!!!\n");
    return 0;
}

/*
** Функция выхода из Модуля
*/
static void __exit lab_driver_exit(void)
{
    /* Удаляет 1 запись процесса */
    //remove_proc_entry("lab/struct_info", parent);

    /* Удяление полностью /proc/lab */
    proc_remove(parent);
    
    pr_info("Device Driver Remove...Done!!!\n");
}

module_init(lab_driver_init);
module_exit(lab_driver_exit);
```

My makefile:

```
obj-m += driver.c
all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The problem i am facing:

```
sudo make
make -C /lib/modules/5.11.0-37-generic/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-37-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'. Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:211: archscripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-37-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

Also i installed a list of tools for developing drivers: `sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev flex bison openssl libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libiberty-dev autoconf` and `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-'uname -r'`. So i don't know how to fix this problem and maybe you know.

Comment: Can you please set your regional or locale settings to English, and rebuild so we can read the error messages you get?

Comment: updated my post

Comment: Not sure if it's the same on Ubuntu, but on Fedora you need the `kernel-devel` and `kernel-debug-devel` packages. They provide a release and a debug version of `relocs_32.c`. The package names are likely different on Ubuntu

Comment: `/lib/modules/5.11.0-37-generic/build` expects to be a symbolic link to the kernel source for which you are building the module.  See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.149/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.rst#L72

Comment: @stark didn't help

Comment: Your Makefile seems to be missing the <TAB> formatting after the target, so:
`obj-m += driver.c
 all:
       <TAB>make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
  clean:
       <TAB>make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean`

Where <TAB> are just one tabulator key to indent.